# Why is $\frac{d}{dt}[\frac{1}{y}] = \frac{d}{dt}[\cos{x}]$ result in an application of the chain rule in related functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

Why does the below step result in a chain rule?
Intuitively, I would just differentiate it against y and x resulting in $-y^{-2} = -\sin{x}$.

[Khan Acad](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-diff-contextual-applications-new/ab-4-4/v/differentiating-related-functions) mentioned something about relating y = y(t) and x = x(t), but my brain is struggling to comprehend why it can just be related like this... (Though I could just be getting it completely wrong)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think it is easier if you separate out *differentiation* from *derivatives*.  Differentiation is the process of converting an equation of variables to an equation of differentials.  A derivative is a ratio of derivatives.  I think that separating these processes makes the whole of calculus easier to understand.

So, in your case, you have:

$$y^{-1} = \cos(x)$$

If we just differentiate it, we get:

$$ -y^{-2}\,dy = -\sin(x)\, dx$$

Here, no variable has a privileged place.  We aren't differentiating with respect to anything.  Every expression is followed by the differential of the variables.

The question wants $\frac{dy}{dt}$.  To do that, start by solving for $dy$:

$$ dy = \sin(x)\,y^2\,dx $$

Now, just divide both sides by $dt$ (you can do anything you want to an equation, as long as you do it to both sides - even dividing by a brand new differential):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin(x)\,y^2\,\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: Wow this is quite a simple way to think about it. Is it fair to say, we can treat $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as units or variables of the equation?

Comment: @olif9837 You basically treat them as variables.  You can actually think of them as functions, though it is slightly more complicated than that.  Similar to having $\sin x$ be a shortened form of $\sin(x)$, $dx$ is a shortened form of $d(x)$.  This works great for the first derivative.  It *would* work great for the second derivative, except that the notation we use there is terrible.  Google my paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials" or "Simplifying and Refactoring Introductory Calculus" for more information.

Comment: Note that there are preconditions for doing this process, but they are basically the same preconditions that exist for including anything else in an equation, so basically negligible (if you would even think to divide by $dt$, you have probably met the preconditions for dividing by $dt$).  In short, there must be some way of relating $t$ to the rest of the variables.  We don't have to know how to relate $t$ to the variables, we just have to know that, in theory, we could find a way.

Answer (score 2):

It might be somewhat complicated, but the essence of the problem is simple.

We know that the variable $x, y$ is *unknown* functions of $t$, In other words, we know that the some functions $f(t), g(t)$ exist such that $x = f(t), y = g(t)$ but we don't know $yet$ what the actual expression of $f, g$ look like. It maybe look like $f(t) = 2t$, or $f(t) = \tan(t) + 12$ or anything can be. But thanks to the problem, we know some relation between $f$ and $g$.

We know $\frac{1}{y} = \cos(x)$, can be written as $\frac{1}{g(t)} = \cos(f(t))$. You can see that there is *no* $x, y$ in the relation. So you can just simply differentiate it with $t$(because LHS and RHS are always equal).

According to your idea, just simply differentiate LHS and RHS with $x$, can be also applied, but we can't get $\frac{dy}{dt}$, which we want. Because:
$$\frac{1}{y} = \cos{x}$$
If we differnetiate both side with $\frac{d}{dx}$:
$$-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sin(x)\frac{dx}{dx}$$
Which is same as:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2 \sin(x)$$

Comment: Is my answer also correct ?

Comment: @Spectre I think you might consider more cases; you induce $x = -2t$ from $\frac{dx}{dt} = -2$ but it can be $x = -2t + C$ 'cause general forms of antiderivatives

Comment: you are right... anyway, is the answer still worth staying in  here ?

Comment: Ok, I see, my way doesn't give us $\frac{}{}$. //// So, we (Step 1) switch to using g(t) & f(t) mid equation, $\frac{dg(t)}{dt} = \cos{f(t)}$, to which we apply the chain rule(Step 2), $\frac{d}{dt}[-\frac{1}{(g(t))^2}] \cdot \frac{d}{dt} g(t)$ = $\frac{d}{dt} \cos{f(t)} \cdot \frac{d}{dt} f(t)$. Then (Step 3)  switch it back to y & x instead which is what results in $1\frac{1}{y^2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} = -\sin{x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$. Is my understanding correct here? Otherwise can you point me to what I need to brush up on?

Comment: @olif9837 yes! That's implied between the steps because $x, y$ is not a free variable but depends on $t$

Comment: Right so x and y are fully dependent on what t is. Gotcha. Thank you so much! Calculus is tedious huh!!

Comment: @olif9837 "Calculus is tedious huh !!" - never :)

Comment: And these are just the basic....! @Spectre can't imagine when matrixes come into play...

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think that it is the chain rule. Since we have the value for $\dfrac 1y$ as $\cos{x}$, you can directly substitute it, if you are looking for $\dfrac{d}{dt}[\dfrac 1y]$. (I say this about the title, to make it clearer)

Here's another solution I tried to make. Hope you find this one helpful.

---

$\because \dfrac{dx}{dt} = -2, dx = -2dt \implies \int{dx} = \int{-2dt} =\implies x = -2t + C$ (preparing stuff for application in chain rule)

(If the correct answer is $0$, let's take $C = 0$, which makes $x = -2t$. Also, it (taking $C = 0$) might work, since no special graph to find the intercept has been given or because of lack of reference to anything that alters the value of $C$. )

$\implies \cos{x} = \cos{(-2t)}$

$\therefore , \dfrac 1y = \cos{x} = \cos(-2t), y = \dfrac 1{\cos{(-2t)}}$

$\therefore, \dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{d(\dfrac 1{\cos{(-2t)}})}{dt} = \dfrac{-\sin{(-2t)}}{\cos^2{(-2t)}}\times-2 = \dfrac{2\sin(-2t)}{\cos^2{(-2t)}}$ (Here's where we use the chain rule, alongside the quotient rule.)

Now we are looking for the derivative at $t = -\dfrac \pi2$ , that is , $x = \pi$ (since $x = -2t$ as we get from the integration above), so just plug in the values, you get $\dfrac {dy}{dt} = 0$.

For an understandable solution, since we have $x = -2t$, we can write $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{2\sin(-2t)}{\cos^2{(-2t)}}$ as $-2\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{2\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$ (we have to remove the $-2$ factor in $x$). Now plug in $x = \pi$ and you get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$
$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -2\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$

Comment: There is a thing that $\dfrac {dx}{dt} = -2$, when integrated, yields $x = -2t + C$, but for now, let's take $C = 0$, if $0$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for this but I'm still a noob and not learned integrals yet. Once I get there I'll be sure to come back to this!

Comment: @olif9837 , even I am a noob, except that I learnt a bit of it :)